# multiBamSummary output chromosome region annotate issue

Tags: deeptools

I was looking how to take readcount from ATAC seq data , this [post](https://www.biostars.org/p/320394/#409383) which suggested to use bedtools and featurecounts to take out readcounts .But multiBamSummary seems to be pretty straight forward. Now I have my count file but only issue is there are no gene names. So now is it possible to annotate these chromosome regions? if so how ?

Any suggestion or help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you used a BED file as input then the output is in the same order, so just merge the two files together.

Comment: i used bam files in case of bed files but yes the orders are same .But would that help me in annotating the region ?

Comment: I assume you used `multiBamSummary BED-file`, did you use `multiBamSummary bins` instead?

Comment: "multiBamSummary bins" yes that is what i used what i saw in the manual

Comment: They're bins of the size you specified that tile the genome then.

Comment: okay.Now any way to annotate those regions ? the intervals which i see in the output ,as i would like to take that for downstream analysis where i would like to see the gene name

Comment: Overlap/intersect them with a GTF file.

Comment: Conceptual doubt ,would it be similar to annotating the peaks like that of homer annnotate peak function ? or I can simply map the the chromosome start end to gtf file.

Comment: "Conceptual question" (a doubt is generally not something one "has" in English). I'd just simply map things to the GTF file.

Comment: thank you @Devon clarifying my question and the English